# Removing sub-div doesn't trigger transition

Tags: css, transition, effect

I have a div in div (child and parent) and if I hide the child then the parent's height is lowered - the parent's size depends on the content (the child's size).

What I want to achieve is to have a transition effect when the parent's height gets lowered but the problem is that the transition is not triggered.

I've red about "non-triggering transition" problems and all seems to have something in common: the initial values are not set right, But I think mine are OK. Am I right?

Q: How to get transition working when hiding/removing the child from the parent?

```css
#sub {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
.main:hover #sub {
    display: none;
}
.main {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 800px;
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
    color: white;

    -webkit-transition: min-height 500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: min-height 500ms linear;
    -ms-transition: min-height 500ms linear;
    -o-transition: min-height 500ms linear;
    transition: min-height 500ms linear;

    -webkit-transition: max-height 500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: max-height 500ms linear;
    -ms-transition: max-height 500ms linear;
    -o-transition: max-height 500ms linear;
    transition: max-height 500ms linear;

    -webkit-transition: height 500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: height 500ms linear;
    -ms-transition: height 500ms linear;
    -o-transition: height 500ms linear;
    transition: height 500ms linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <p>Hover</p>
    <div id="sub"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that `display:none;` and `transition`s don’t work together.

Comment: Thats bad.. do you know any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, `display:none;` and `transition`s or `animation`s don’t work together, because `display` is not an *animatable* property. The CSS basically ignores the transition in that case.

As for the workaround question: you have to define specifically how the CSS has to behave when you want something to disappear or to appear. Should it fade in / away? Should it lose / gain height or width? Other than that you can also try [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) which is animatable.

This has the effect of the parent being lowered as the child slowly disappears:

```css
.main {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 800px;
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
#sub {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    transition: height 500ms linear;
}
.main:hover #sub {
    height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <p>Hover</p>
    <div id="sub"></div>
</div>
```

I have removed all those vendor-prefixes for simplicity. Tell me if this is what you want and if you want anything else done with the transitions.